# Electric field due to a current carrying loop

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I want to know how I can calculate the radiated electric field in the far zone of the loop.

- Knowing that the loop is in center at the origin of a x-y plane
- Knowing that the loop as a time-harmonic current $i(t)=A*cos(wt)$
- Knowing that $R<<\lambda$

I know that $\nabla B$ due to a loop in the far away region is equal to zero.
And that the same equation in the near field is equal to $\mu*J$ but I can't evolve further.

Points I'm thinking about going.

- Getting the total magnetic flux passing through the loop?
- Trying to use the Faraday's Law of Induction to get the electric field?

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.
Antoine

Comment: See for example Thidé EMFT Book equations 6.57 for a traditional determination of the radiative fields here: https://web.archive.org/web/20151211002805/http://www.physics.irfu.se/CED/Book/EMFT_Book.pdf